# How do I edit a docx-document received in Gmail online on Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive, document-management

I received a docx-document on my Gmail. I clicked "view", and then the "Save in Google Docs" button.

Now in Google Docs, I can only view the document but not edit it.

How do I edit the document in Google Docs? Can I transformit to a similar format and then edit it? how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Official GMail Blog](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/06/view-doc-attachments-right-in-your.html) you should be able to do this already:

> Just click the "View" link at the bottom of a Gmail message and the viewer will take it from there. If you decide you want to edit the file, clicking "Edit online" will open it in Google Docs, or you can download it to your desktop from there.

This is in a post dated June 25, 2010.

Answer (score 3):

If you are currently viewing the document in Google Docs, but can't edit it, go to *File* → *Open With* → **Google Docs**.

This then converts the file for editing.

Or, if you're viewing it in the Gmail viewer, click the **Open With** button at the bottom and do the same thing. This is a quick-and-easy option if you just want to do it for an individual file that was opened from Gmail.

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me:

- Settings (Gear icon)
- Upload settings
- Convert uploaded files to Google Docs format